# Is a generalization of Padoa inequality correct?

Tags: inequalities

Padoa's inequality is named after Alessandro Padoa (1868-1937):

Let $a$, $b$, $c$ be sidelengths of a given triangle $\triangle ABC$ then

$$(b+c-a)(c+a-b)(a+b-c) \le abc .$$

> > **My question:** Is the following generalization of Padoa's inequality  corect?

Let $a_i>0$ for $1\le i\le n$ and let $$S:=a_1+a_2+....+a_n.$$ Suppose that $$b_i:=S-(n-1)a_i \ge 0\quad\text{ for} \quad 1\le i\le n.$$ 
Then

$$\prod_{i=1}^n b_i \leq \prod_{1}^{n} a_i .$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since $a_i=\frac{S-b_i}{n-1}=\frac{\sum_j b_j -b_i}{n-1}$ we can write
$$\prod_{i=1}^n a_i=\prod_{i=1}^n \left(\frac{\sum_{j\neq i}b_i}{n-1}\right)\geq \prod_{i=1}^n \left(\prod_{j\neq i}b_i\right)^{1/n-1}=\prod_{i=1}^n b_i$$
by the Arithmetic-Geometric mean inequality.